# MVC Apply antiforgery token by default

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, security, antiforgerytoken

ASP.NET MVC doesn't apply the antiforgery token by default so you have to do it manually every time which is a potential security issue.

I'm thinking of applying the antiforgery by default with some javascipt. Can this cause a security problem? Or are there better solutions?

1) Add the token in all possible forms on the page. This by adding the following script in the main layout.

```
<script>
    var csrfToken = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").append(csrfToken);
    });
</script>
```

2) Verify the token on each post:

[make sure each controller method has a ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937962/make-sure-each-controller-method-has-a-validateantiforgerytoken-attribute)

Comment: I'm going to be that guy.... Do you really need to validate this token on each request? Most people only use it on POST methods to prevent CSRF (assuming they are using POST vs GET correctly).

Comment: Only on post requests indeed