# Apply ValidateAntiForgeryToken on all action method except HttpGet in asp.net core

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We are calling service controller action method using jquery ajax post request. For this I need to pass antiforgery token with every request. I did this in below way:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
        if (settings.type.toUpperCase() != "POST") return;
        jqxhr.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', $(".AntiForge" + " input").val())
    });
```

and in _Layout page

```
<span class="AntiForge"> @Html.AntiForgeryToken() </span>
```

But, now i want to apply `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` token attribute to all action method inside controllers except action method with `[HttpGet]` verb.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Also, what about HEAD and other verbs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make sure each controller method has a ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937962/make-sure-each-controller-method-has-a-validateantiforgerytoken-attribute)

Comment: @Luke we are using only GET and POST methods. And your second link might work for me need to check. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck.  You'll probably find that your server will get hit by HEAD requests too by all kinds of services.